# Golang address operators and (*int)(Type) syntax

Tags: go

Starting to play around with `golang` and was looking at a custom `json.Unmarshal`. In a blog post the had the following:

```
type FlexInt int

func (fi *FlexInt) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if data[0] != '"' {
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*int)(fi))
    }
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *fi = FlexInt(i)
    return nil
}
```

And I understand what it is doing - but I dont understand `(*int)(fi)` part. Looking at the value of the `fi` pointer it is the same as `(*int)(fi)` - `(*int)(fi) == fi`. Yet when I change that line to simply `fi` it then does an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression [converts](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) `fi` to an `*int`.  The result contains the same address, but has a different type.

If a `*FlexInt` is passed to `json.Unmarshal`, then `json.Unmarshal` will call the `*FlexInt.UnmarshalJSON` method which calls `json.Unmarshal` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same pointer, but with a different type. When `json.Unmarshal` is called with an `interface{}` that contains a `FlexInt*`, it calls `FlexInt`'s `UnmarshalJSON` method. When it's called with an `interface{}` that contains an `int*`, it uses the builtin behavior. Since `FlexInt` and `int` have the same underlying type, it's acceptable to convert a pointer to one into a pointer to the other, but it's the "actual" type that the interface will be marked with.